# Adding a twist to a 3d surface

Tags: geometry, 3d

Before I start I'm not a mathematician so bear with me...

I have an equation that takes the form of a tornado shape, its described by the following equation:
$$z = 2\ln(x^2 + y^2)$$
I want to add a twist to this curve in cartesian corrdinates but have no idea how to do it. Is there a way to change this curve to add a twist whilst describing the whole object in a single cartesian equation?

[Just for clarification heres the kind of twist i am refering to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0915A.png)

Comment: Can you say what you mean by a twist?

Comment: A "twist"?  Can you be more clear?  Perhaps you might draw a picture?

Comment: Also, this is not a curve, it is a surface, right? It looks like a logarithmic funnel. It's $z=4\ln r$.

Comment: Since you are not a math-y person by admission, it might be useful to check out the limitations of 3D shapes you can get when $z$ is [a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_line_test) of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I suspect you'll be able to define your shape [parametrically](https://christopherchudzicki.github.io/MathBox-Demos/parametric_curves_3D.html).  I'm doubtful that "a single cartesian equation" exists that gives what you desire.

Comment: Do you want to maintain the tornado (?) shape? First you need to add the "flower" which could be with trigonometric functions. The effect of rotation could be added by modifying phase in the trigonometric function (may be even as function of z?) -